# Extracting from wrapper to map of vector

Tags: c++, stl, containers, boost-python

The context is that of an embedded python script and calling the interpreter
from a code written in C++.

The C++ and Python codes below summarise the techniques to wrap in C++, use in Python and then extract back in C++ the two most common STL containers:

- std::vector
- std::map

It focuses more particularly on the case when they hold std::string type elements.

One of the difficulties here for coders unfamiliar with the boost python library is that the boost iterators and iterable suites are mapping a concept which is common to both languages but which nonetheless is treated fairly differently in the two respective programming environments.

Drawing on existing material and personal experiments, I have clarified to myself what seems to be the intended way for the most common usage. Nothing that has not been shown elsewhere but it does feel as though boost::python can tolerate a bit of redundancy in terms of examples and illustrating cases.

There is one case that I do not seem to be able to solve so far: returning a wrapped vector of strings to C++. I would appreciate it if someone could enlight me on this.

The code is intended to be self-contained and serves two purposes. Firstly, it is meant to help people who, like myself, are looking for more examples of simple use cases. It also shows that manipulating a vector of double is more straight-forward than a vector string.

In the C++ example below I get a run-time error saying essentially:
typedef std::vector VecStr;
class boost::python::class> struct boost::python::deltail::not_specified_struc from this Python object of typeMapStringVectorString.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

PS: I had to reconstruct the amended code from memory and there might be some syntax errors. I correct them as soon as I have access to connected machine.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/map_indexing_suite.hpp>
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(idctor)
{
    typedef std::vector<string> VectorString;
    typedef std::map<string, VectorString> MapVectorString;
    typedef class_<VectorString, shared_ptr<VectorString>> pyVectorString;
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<std::vector<double> >("DoubleVector")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<double> >());

    class_<std::vector<std::string>,shared_ptr<VectorString> >("VectorString")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<string> >());

    class_<std::map<std::string, double> >("StringDoubleMap")
        .def(map_indexing_suite<std::map<std::string, double> >());

    class_<std::map<string, string> >("MapStringString")
        .def(map_indexing_suite<std::map<std::string, string> >());

    class_<std::map<string, VectorString> , shared_ptr<MapVectorString>>("MapStringVectorString")
        .def(map_indexing_suite<std::map<std::string, VectorString> >());
}


typedef std::vector<string> VectorString;
typedef  class_<VectorString> pyVectorString;
typedef class_<VectorString, shared_ptr<VectorString>> pyMapVectorString;


int main()
{
    PyImport_AppendInittab("idctor", &PyInit_idctor);
    Py_Initialize();
    try {

        //PyInit_hello();
        object main
            = object(handle<>(borrowed(PyImport_AddModule("__main__"))));
        object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");
        PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\n");
        exec_file("G:\\Developments\\VisualStudio\\BoostPythonSTLContainers\\stlcontainers.py", main_namespace);
        //       Getting back an Python object containing a 
        //            vector of double, extracting the 
        //            corresponding typed C++ object and using it
        object pyv = main_namespace["v"];
        //---------------->  this works <--------------
        std::vector<double>& v = extract<vector<double>&>(pyv);
        v.push_back(665);
        //----------------> this does not <----------------
        //       Getting back a working Python object 
        object pyvs = main_namespace["vs"];
        //   Attempting to convert it back to its true C++ type
        //    Here the conversion fails:
        VectorString& vs = extract<VectorString&>(pyvs);
        vs.push_back("not yet the beast");

        //   Attempt to do the same with a map of string to vector of strings
        object pymvs = main_namespace["mvs"];

        //----------------> Clearly this fails too <--------------
        pyMapVectorString& mvs = extract<pyMapVectorString&>(pymvs);
        object pyvs = mvs["this "];
        VectorString& vs = extract<VectorString&>(pyvs);
        vs.push_back({ "should ","work" });
    }
    catch (error_already_set) {
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the (working) python code:

```
# 
#    All the python code below is working fine
#         (the issue is converting back in C++)
import idctor
#defining a function to print a container
def tostr(container):
    string ='['
    for i in container:
        string += str(i)+","
    string+='end]'
    return string

# Turning it into a instance method
idctor.DoubleVector.__str__ = tostr

# instantiating a vector of doubles
v = idctor.DoubleVector()
v.append(1.0)
v.append(2.0)
for i in v:
    print(i)

#instantiating a vector of strings
idctor.VectorString.__str__ = tostr
vs = idctor.VectorString()
vs.append("he2")
vs.append("he1")
print("Directly: ", vs)
for s in vs:
    print(s)
m = idctor.StringDoubleMap()

# instantiating a map of string to doubles
m["a"] = 1
m["b"] = 2
for i in m:
    print(i)
print(m)

#instantiating a map of string to strings
ms = idctor.MapStringString()
ms["a"]="he1"
ms["b"]="he2"
for s in ms:
    print(s)

#instantiating a map of string to vectors of strings
mvs = idctor.MapStringVectorString()
mvs["a"]=vs 
vs2=idctor.VectorString()
vs2.append("cy")
vs2.append("ve")
mvs["b"]=vs2
for vs in mvs:
    print(vs)
```

Comment: "a verbose and rather cryptic error" then you should include that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue can be corrected by entering a NoProxy=true option in the template declaration of the class. The second issue persist and it seems that a special converter from python should be built to handle this case. I am yet to figure out how to do it. I found, however, an -- arguably ugly -- workaround relying on the python objects themselves. Just added in case some people want to follow this path.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(idctor)
 {
 typedef std : : vector <string> VectorString;
 typedef std::map<string, VectorString> MapVectorString;
 typedef class_<Vector String, shared_ptr<VectorString>> pyVectorString;
 using namespace boost::python;

 //                    NOTICE THE TRUE IN THE 
//          vector_indexing_suite second template argument
 class_<std::vector <std::string>, Shared_ptr <VectorString> > ("VectorString")
.def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<string>, true >());


 class <std::map<std::string, double> > ("StringDoubleMap")
.def(map_indexing_suite<std::map<std::string, double>, true >());

 class <std::map<string, string> > ("MapStringString")
.def(map indexing suite<std::map<string, string>, true >());

 class <MapVectorString, shared ptrkMapVectorString>, boost::noncopyable>("MapStringVectorString")
.def(map_indexing_suite<MapVectorString, true >());

 }

 typedef std::vector<string> VectorString;
 typedef class_<VectorString> pyVectorString;
 typedef std::map<string, VectorString> MapVectorString;
 typedef class_<MapVectorString, shared_ptr<MapVectorString>> pyMapVectorString;

int main()
{

PyImport_AppendInittab ("idctor", &PyInit_idctor) ;
Py_Initialize();
try {
object main
= object (handle<> (borrowed (Pylimport_AddModule ("__main__"))));
object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");
exec_file ("WrappedSTLContainer.py", main_namespace);

// Getting back a vector of double in C++ and using it
object pyv = main_namespace ["v"];
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - > this works <- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
std::vector<double>& v = extract<vector<double>&>(pyv);
v.push_back(665) ;
// Getting back a vector of string in C++ and attempting to use it
object pyvs = main namespace["vs"];
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - > this works now <- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
std::vector<std::string>& vs = extract<vector<string>&>(pyvs);
vs.push_back("Almost the Beast");
cout << "From C++ this time -> vs[2] " << vs[2] << endl;

// Getting back a map of string-vector of string in C++
// and trying to use it
object pymvs = main namespace["mvs"];
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - > this still does not work - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// pyMapVectorString& mvs = extract< pyMapVectorString&> (pymvs);

//------------------------->  Work around: working in python
 object method = pymvs.attr("__setitem__");
 VectorString vs3;
 vs3.push_back(" should ");
 vs3.push_back("work");
 object ignored = method ("this", vs3);
 const char * s = extract<const char *> (pymvs.attr("__getitem__")("this ").attr ("__str__") ());
 cout << s  << endl;
 }
 catch (error_already_set) { 
   PyErr_Print();
   return 1;
 }

 Py_Finalize();
 return 0;
 }
```